# SELECT query outputting each single result six times

Tags: php, mysql

**This query outputs each result 6 times:**  So, for one row with a body of 'ayo', it will be outputted as: ayo
ayo
ayo
ayo
ayo
ayo

```
function get_comments($page_type, $spot) {
        $query = mysql_query("
                              SELECT
                              comments.user_id AS user_id,
                              comments.page_type AS page_type,
                              comments.spot AS spot,
                              comments.comment AS comment,
                              comments.timestamp AS timestamp,
                              users.first_name AS first_name,
                              users.last_name AS last_name
                              FROM comments, users
                              WHERE page_type = '$page_type' AND spot = '$spot' AND (comments.user_id = users.user_id OR comments.user_id = '0')
                              ORDER BY timestamp DESC
                             ");

        while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

            $comment = $fetch['comment'];
            $timestamp = $fetch['timestamp'];
            $timestamp_date = date('M d y\'', $timestamp);
            $timestamp_time = date('g:m', $timestamp);
            $comments_user_id = $fetch['user_id'];

                if(date('H', $timestamp) > 12) {
                    $am_pm = 'pm';
                    } else {
                        $am_pm = 'am';
                        }

            $first_name = $fetch['first_name'];
            $last_name = $fetch['last_name'];

            ?>

            <div id="replies">

                <?php if($comments_user_id == '0') {echo 'Guest';} else { echo $first_name.' '.$last_name; } ?><br />
                <?php echo $timestamp_date; ?><br />
                <?php echo $comment; ?>

            </div>

            <?php

            }
        }
```

**In here $page_type and $spot refer to:**  http://localhost/$page_type/$spot

Comment: can u post the code where you are outputting? The problem might be there, if not in the data itself

Comment: How many `comments` have `user_id = 0`?

Comment: You're right! if user_id = 0 it multiplies.  How would I get around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting duplicates because your implicit join condition contains this:

```
OR comments.user_id = '0'
```

and you have multiple rows with `comments.user_id = 0`. Each of these `user_id = 0` rows will appear match your join condition and that will lead to duplicates. The solution is to fix your data so that each comment has a valid `user_id` where "valid" means "has an entry in `users`" and the drop the `comments.user_id = 0` part of your join condition. And while you're at it, switch to InnoDB tables and add foreign keys to enforce this referential integrity constraint.

BTW, if `user_id` is an integer then you really shouldn't be quoting it; you're making the database do unnecessary work and building a bad habit that will cause you some pain and suffering if you every use another database. You should also switch to an explicit join:

```
from comments join users on comments.user_id = users.id
where page_type = '$page_type' and spot = '$spot'
```

Comment: How would I make a guest a valid user.  If the $_SESSION['user_id'] is not set than the user_id is set to 0.  How would change that?

Comment: @Graham: You could add an entry to `users` with and ID of zero and use that as your guest account, then tweak the login stuff to not allow "guest" to login.

Answer (score 1):

Because of your `(comments.user_id = users.user_id OR comments.user_id = '0')` clause, every guest comment will appear as many times as there are records in `users`. Which, apparently, is six.

**Edited to add:**

I guess you want something like this:

```
SELECT comments.user_id AS user_id,
       comments.page_type AS page_type,
       comments.spot AS spot,
       comments.comment AS comment,
       comments.timestamp AS timestamp,
       COALESCE(users.first_name, 'Guest') AS first_name,
       COALESCE(users.last_name, 'User') AS last_name
  FROM comments
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN users
    ON users.user_id = comments.user_id
 WHERE comments.page_type = '$page_type'
   AND comments.spot = '$spot'
 ORDER BY comments.timestamp DESC
;
```

but I agree with "mu is too short" that you should re-evaluate your table design. Using `comments.user_id = 0` to mean "guest comment", when there's no record with `users.user_id = 0`, is not great, since it leaves you with an "almost foreign key" relationship. A full foreign key relationship would make your table structure easier to understand and to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("
                      SELECT
                      comments.user_id AS user_id,
                      comments.page_type AS page_type,
                      comments.spot AS spot,
                      comments.comment AS comment,
                      comments.timestamp AS timestamp,
                      users.first_name AS first_name,
                      users.last_name AS last_name
                      FROM comments, users
                      WHERE page_type = '$page_type' AND spot = '$spot' AND (comments.user_id = users.user_id OR comments.user_id = '0')
                      GROUP BY comments.user_id
                      ORDER BY timestamp DESC
                    ");
```

Comment: That only shows a max of one comment per user.  So, it will show a max of one comment for Guest and no more than one for each unique user.

Answer (score 0):

I am not as familiar with MySQL as I am with MS T-SQL. But it looks to me like you are cross-joining your tables. There should probably be a JOIN between users and comments. Otherwise, each comment will be joined to every user.

HERE is a link to JOIN specifics in MySQL.

I may miss some MySQL-specifics on the syntax here, and I can;t test this, but here goes:

THIS will return those records for users with associated comments:

```
SELECT 
    comments.user_id AS user_id,
    comments.page_type AS page_type,
    comments.spot AS spot,
    comments.comment AS comment,
    comments.timestamp AS timestamp,
    users.first_name AS first_name,
    users.last_name AS last_name
FROM 
    comments INNER JOIN users
    ON comments.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE page_type = '$page_type' 
AND spot = '$spot' 
AND (comments.user_id = users.user_id OR comments.user_id = '0')
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

and THIS will return all user records, and will match comment records where they exist:
    SELECT 
        comments.user_id AS user_id,
        comments.page_type AS page_type,
        comments.spot AS spot,
        comments.comment AS comment,
        comments.timestamp AS timestamp,
        users.first_name AS first_name,
        users.last_name AS last_name
    FROM 
        comments INNER JOIN users
    ON comments.user_id = users.user_id
    WHERE page_type = '$page_type' 
    AND spot = '$spot' 
    AND (comments.user_id = users.user_id OR comments.user_id = '0')
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC

Comment: The `WHERE` clause seems to take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query))
```

change the while syntax to above

and change this syntax code

```
WHERE page_type = '$page_type' AND spot = '$spot' AND (comments.user_id = users.user_id OR comments.user_id = '0')
```

to

```
WHERE page_type = '$page_type' AND spot = '$spot' AND (comments.user_id = users.user_id)
```